# Raster layer not clipping to polygon boundary and yielding block extent in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, clip, extents

I am using ArcMap.

I want to graphically display my NDVI distribution, but I had to convert my NDVI raster layer from continuous values to integer in order to view the attribute table (I used the Int() in raster calculator). The output was correct, except that is included extraneous 0 values in a block around my original boundaries (the multi-colour forest area).

I was able to successfully clip this out with one layer (clipped to polygon boundaries of the forest area, and yes I had the "input features" box selected), but now the clipping isn't working anymore and still yielding this large block extent (see screenshot below) despite nothing in my procedure having changed from the initial successful clip.

I tried again and switched it up by using different features in the clip tool and alternatively using extract by mask, but still no success.

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Every cell in a raster has to have some value, even if it's a nodata value. If you want to not see the purple area, set 0 as a nodata value, or make it transparent.

Comment: Go to environment settings and set extent to one of forest.